# backgroundworker in infinite loop

Tags: doevents

Except `doevent()` is another way that, in this infinite loop run another control in form.

I wanted to do it with backgroundworker, but I failed.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        while (true)
        {
          Application.DoEvents();         //how i can use the backgrondworker in this place
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The question and sample are confusing to me but what I think you are asking is how to use the BackgroundWorker class.

The [Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) for this class is pretty helpful and has sample code towards the bottom.